# Insert cursor only copies 80% of data due to lock?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, schema-locks

I have two tables:

1) feature class (i.e. table in code) = sites under "SiteID" and mean july data under "JulyMean". The sites have duplicates, therefore there are several groups of same sites. There are other fields in this table. There are 280 sites(rows) in total.

2) summary statistics table (i.e. stat_table in code) = summary statistics table containing the sites under "SiteID" with max mean July data under "MAX_JulyMean". There are 23 sites(rows) in total.

I'd like to create a new feature class (i.e. newtable_path) which contains all the sites identified in stat_table with the maximum mean data, however i'd like to include the other fields from the feature class table. I used search cursors to match the site id from the stat table with the feature class table. Then i insert the feature class table's data into the new feature class table. The insert cursor only copies 19/23 sites into the new table (all 19 rows are in order meaning the insertcursor is writing as should). I've read that the problem is due to locks etc... but I don't know how to release the lock.

How do I have all 23 rows copied instead of just 19?

```py
#import packages 
import arcpy from arcpy 
import * from arcpy 
import env from arcpy.sa 
import * import os
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#Input 
workspace = r"C:\Research\Water_Temperature_Analysis\Water_Temperature_80PercentOfJuly.gdb"
table =r"C:\Research\Water_Temperature_Analysis\Water_Temperature_80PercentOfJuly.gdb\DFOSLC_80andabove"
field = "SiteID" # field containing groups 
field1 = "JulyMean" #field with max and min 
stat_table = r"C:\Research\Water_Temperature_Analysis\Water_Temperature_80PercentOfJuly.gdb\DFOSLC_80andabove_extremeMaxMin"
    newtable = "DFOSLC_80andabove_ExtremeMeans"

    #enter workspace folder
    env.workspace = workspace
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    #Find max and min
    #arcpy.Statistics_analysis(table, stat_table, [[field1, "MAX"],[field1,"MIN"]], field)
    # Create table with max and min 
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(workspace, newtable, "POINT", table) 
    newtable_path= workspace + "\\" + newtable

    # Copy Max Values to new table 
    cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(table) 
    maxfield = "MAX_"+ str(field1) 
    cursor1 = arcpy.SearchCursor(stat_table,[field,maxfield]) 
    cursor2 = arcpy.InsertCursor(newtable_path)
    for row1 in cursor1:    
        for row in cursor:      
            if row1.getValue(field) == row.getValue(field):
                if row1.getValue(maxfield) == row.getValue(field1):
                    cursor2.insertRow(row)
                    row1 = cursor1.next() 
    del cursor2 
    del row, cursor
    del row1, cursor1
```

Comment: what version of ArcMap?

Comment: Product Name: ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop
    Release Version: 10.3.1
    Product Version: 10.3.1.4959

Comment: If you're in 10.3 you should use the `arcpy.da` cursors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone who helped me. I modified Emil Brundage's code and took advantage of the different ways of writing the same cursor to circumvent... The working code is:

```
.
.
.
# create list of site id and max mean
stat_data = set()
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor (stat_table, [field, maxfield])
for row in cursor:
    siteid= row[0]
    maxmean = row[1]
    valset = (siteid,maxmean)
    stat_data.add(valset)

del row, cursor

print stat_data

# find rows that match criteria and copy
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(table)
cursor1 = arcpy.InsertCursor(newtable_path)

for row in cursor:
    siteid_o = row.getValue(field)
    maxmean_o = row.getValue(field1)
    valset_o = (siteid_o, maxmean_o)
    #check if vals are in set
    if valset_o in stat_data:
        cursor1.insertRow(row)
del row, cursorenter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

This line will produce an error because you're mixing the older version of the `cursor` with the newer `data access version` of the `cursor`:

`cursor1 = arcpy.SearchCursor(stat_table,[field,maxfield])`

Your best bet is to break up your various cursors into their own iterations instead of having all three opened at once. Make use of sets and lists to store data in memory.

Maybe something like this:

```
#enter workspace folder
env.workspace = workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Find max and min
#arcpy.Statistics_analysis(table, stat_table, [[field1, "MAX"],[field1,"MIN"]], field)
# Create table with max and min 
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(workspace, newtable, "POINT", table) 
newtable_path= workspace + "\\" + newtable

#empty set to store site ID and mean/max values
values = set ()
#cursor and store valuves in set
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor (stat_table)
for row in cursor:
    #get values
    siteId = row.getValue (field)
    maxVal = row.getValue (maxfield)
    vals = (siteId, maxVal)
    #update set
    values.add (vals)
del row, cursor

#store rows that match criteria
rows = []
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(table)
for row in cursor:
    siteId = row.getValue (field)
    maxVal = row.getValue (field1)
    vals = (siteId, maxVal)
    #check if vals are in set
    if vals in values:
        #if yes, add row to list of rows
        rows += [row]
del row, cursor

#insert cursor
cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(newtable_path)
#iterate rows
for row in rows:
    cursor.insertRow (row)

del cursor
```

Comment: The same row is being copied 23 times.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to skip a row, `row1 = cursor1.next()` isn't needed when you're already in a loop like `for row1 in cursor1:`. The loop will automatically go to the next record for you.

Next problem is that your `cursor` cursor will complete its iteration after the first run of the `cursor1` loop, so it needs to be reset so it starts over from the beginning. So replace `row1 = cursor1.next()` with `cursor.reset()`.

```
for row1 in cursor1:    
    for row in cursor:      
        if row1.getValue(field) == row.getValue(field):
            if row1.getValue(maxfield) == row.getValue(field1):
                cursor2.insertRow(row)
    cursor.reset()
```

As it is written with the `next()` and no `reset`, it's going to do something like:

1. Load the first row of `cursor1`
2. Load the first row of `cursor`
3. Check to see if the values in `field` match
4. Check to see if the values in `maxfield` and `field1` match
5. If they match, insert a row, and advance `cursor1` to the second row
6. Load the second row of `cursor` to do the same checks
7. *Oops! We're not on the first row of `cursor1` anymore!*
8. Every time we have we match, another row of `cursor1` gets skipped
9. Eventually, we finish all the rows of `cursor`
10. So the `for` loop advances to the next row if `cursor1`, which isn't the second row since it's been advanced by every match.
11. So now with what I assume is the 19th row of `cursor1`:
12. We want to loop the values of `cursor` with the for-loop
13. But the cursor has already been run to the end in the first loop
14. The for-loop has nothing left to loop over so it skips the checks.

Comment: without row1 = cursor1.next(), only the first row is copied to the new table.

Comment: Resetting the cursor caused only the first row to be copied.

Comment: Then maybe you have a logic problem? Try printing out the values of 'field', 'field1', and 'maxfield' in the 'cursor' loop to see if the logic makes sense.

Comment: Logic seems right since the rows being copied are in the right order. The values being printed are only for the first 19 rows.

Comment: still giving first 19 rows when i use cursor.reset().

Comment: If it prints 19 rows the problem isn't file locking. You might spot something if you count your loop iterations and print out the counts. Does `cursor1` run 23 loops every time? Does `cursor` run 280 loops?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to doing the looping would be to use a sql query in one of the search cursors (untested):

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newtable_path) as output_cursor:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(stat_table, [field, maxfield]) as stat_cursor: 
        for stat_row in stat_cursor:    
            field_value = stat_row[0]
            max_value = stat_row[1]
            SQL = " %s = '%s' AND %s = '%s' " % (field, field_value, field1, max_value )
            print SQL # can paste this into the Select By Attributes window to troubleshoot
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, '*', where_clause=SQL) as site_cursor:
                 for site in site_cursor:
                     output_cursor.insertRow(site)
```